# Задача на цикл for в Java

Tags: java

Начав тренировки, лыжник в первый день пробежал 10 км. Каждый следующий день он увеличивал пробег на 10% от пробега предыдущего дня. Определить:
а) пробег лыжника за второй, третий, ..., десятый день тренировок;
б) какой суммарный путь он пробежал за первые 7 дней тренировок.
Для того, чтобы решить задачу полностью(два пункта) нужно решать только в одном файле(то есть не создавать файл для пункта б))?

```
public class Zlat572 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double start = 10.0;

        System.out.println("Probeg za 1 deni: " + start);
        for (int d = 2; d <= 10; d++) {
            start += (10.0 * start) / 100.0;
            System.out.println("Probeg za " + d + " deni: " + start);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Так. Вопросительный знак в тексте есть. Вопроса - нет.

Comment: @igor Почему это? Наверное неточно сформулировал. Я имел ввиду, чтобы решить задачу(решить пункт а) и пункт б)) нужно их решить в одном файле, то есть не создавать отдельный файл для пункта а) и б) или наоборот, то есть создать файл для пункта а) и решить его и также для б).

Comment: При чем здесь какие-то файлы? Откуда мы знаем, сколько там должно быть файлов? Где вычисление суммарного пути за семь дней?

Comment: Я про это и говорю, чтобы вычислить сумму за 7 дней, нужно ее решить отдельно или в том же где решен пункт а)

Comment: Мы-то откуда это можем знать? Решайте где хотите.

Comment: Вот я и это спрашиваю, нужно в одном все решить или создать 2 отдельных для а) и б)

Comment: Можно вообще без файлов все решить. Нужны тут Файлы или нет только вы можете знать

Comment: Решите все в одном файле и не мучайтесь.

Comment: @Igor в этом и проблема я не знаю как решить в одном. Я создаю отдельна для а) и б)

Comment: Вы знаете анекдот про еврея с двумя петухами?

Comment: Ещё можно для недельного пробега древнее тайное знание использовать `10*(1.1^7-1)/(1.1-1.0)`

Comment: @MBo Человек не может решить один или два файла использовать, а Вы намекаете на слово "прогрессия".

Comment: @Igor Ну то, что формулировки преподавателя могут в ступор ввести  - я понимаю.  Сложный процент-то ведь правильно применил.

Comment: @MBo "In 100 years we have gone from teaching Latin and Greek in high school to teaching Remedial English in college."

Answer (score 1):

```
    double start = 10.0;
    double sum7 = start;

    System.out.println("Probeg za 1 deni: " + start);
    for (int d = 2; d <= 10; d++) {
        start += (10.0 * start) / 100.0;
        if (d <= 7)
            sum7 += start;
        System.out.println("Probeg za " + d + " deni: " + start);
    }
    System.out.println("Za sem' dney " + sum7);
```

> Там нельзя if использовать

```
    double start = 10.0;
    double sum7 = start;

    System.out.println("Probeg za 1 deni: " + start);
    for (int d = 2; d <= 7; d++) {
        start += (10.0 * start) / 100.0;
        sum7 += start;
        System.out.println("Probeg za " + d + " deni: " + start);
    }
    System.out.println("Za sem' dney " + sum7);
    for (int d = 8; d <= 10; d++) {
        start += (10.0 * start) / 100.0;
        System.out.println("Probeg za " + d + " deni: " + start);
    }
```

Comment: Там нельзя if использовать